# Debian minimal install without Libre Office?

Tags: debian, system-installation

I have been trying out a few Linux OSs. Installing the bare minimum systems. However, after installing Debian from the smallest ISO I could find on their site, I saw that Libre Office has been installed. I am looking for a bare minimum install, and I didn't even choose to install the options given such as Debian system utilities. I am surprised that extraneous software like this was included.

Is there a specific ISO or process which will not install the Libre Office?

Comment: You could build your own custom install CD as stated on [debian's homepage](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianCustomCD#Building_a_Custom_Debian_CD_Set).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow most of the [instructions here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/build-lightweight-linux-for-low-end-laptop/).

Use a [NetInstall](https://www.debian.org/CD/netinst/).

Uncheck everything in Software Selection except for Standard system utilities. And don't check Laptop as it says!

This will give to a TEXT based install only, no GUI yet.

Instead of:

```
apt-get install xorg sudo iceweasel pulseaudio
```

I personally would go for Chromium instead of Iceweasel.

Instead of installing `lxde` install `lxde-core`. It will install less cruft.

You then have the basics to add what you want  and no Libre Office.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. This looks like what I'm looking for.